# What is the standard/conventional location for a test text file with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

We've inherited an application that uses a script to import data from a text file, but doesn't test the import script.

I'd like to write some tests for that script, and will need test text files (these are not fixture files).

Where would you normally put those files? A data directory? In the new support directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should decouple your import from the file IO.  Then you should be able to feed in test strings into your importer with out having to make 'test files'.

Comment: And if the test file is 4mb? What then? a 4MB string. Awesome.

Comment: Sounds like you've had to test a few text files.

Lucky for me, the rows of data are small enough to fit in a simple class (or organized well enough to be imported into a data structure like a  FasterCSV object). Then any test files would in fact turn into proper fixtures.

Funny how both of you were right. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I disagree, they are fixtures as they are sample test data you're testing with. They would live in *spec/fixtures*

Comment: Wow, looks like we have a little battle going on. The original script (definitely not written by myself) Does all sorts of wonderful text manipulating where they could've just loaded the data into a regular table. I suppose it

Comment: Perhaps the disagreement is just the difference in how one does unit testing vs how one does functional testing.  Both need to be done.